# How to extract values of one specific specie from a list of list of list in python programming?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list of list in Python data. All values are corresponding to each species in the data. I wanna extract values of specific species. Each corresponding value is in each list.
Suppose I have three species Cu, Ag, Au, and Pt. At three different temperatures their frequencies are given as:

```
Frequency = [[{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}], [{1},{22}, {44}, {54}], [{23}, {43}, {52}]
```

Remember the third value of each list is for "Au" which are 3,44,43. so, I need answer like `[3,44,43]`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Please explain it a little better so we can help.

Comment: This is a list of lists of **sets**, not lists.

Comment: Also, 43 is not the "third" value. The last list only contains 3 items.

Comment: *"three species Cu, Ag, Au, and Pt"* -- Is it three or four?

Comment: You're also missing a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I took liberty to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) so we can index our results by element name.

Since we are extracting your result from a set (e.g. `{1}`) we can use `iter` to return us an iterator over the values, then call `next` to pull the first value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
frequencies = [[{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}], [{1}, {22}, {44}, {54}], [{23}, {99}, {43}, {52}]]
res = defaultdict(list)
for i, element in enumerate(['Cu','Ag','Au','Pt']):
  for j in range(len(frequencies)):
    res[element].append(next(iter(frequencies[j][i])))
for element in res:
  print(f'{element} temperatures was {res[element]}')
```

Output:

```
Cu temperatures was [1, 1, 23]
Ag temperatures was [2, 22, 99]
Au temperatures was [3, 44, 43]
Pt temperatures was [4, 54, 52]
```

Comment: [[-1.8620689655172413, 298.0],
    ...:   [mpf('-395.13386225658188'),
    ...:    mpf('197.56693112829094'),
    ...:    mpf('395.13386225658188'),
    ...:    mpf('-395.13386225658188')]],
    ...:  [[-2.0, 298.0],
    ...:   [mpf('-5795.4864909536747'),
    ...:    mpf('2897.7432454768373'),
    ...:    mpf('5795.4864909536747'),
    ...:    mpf('-5795.4864909536747')]]]
    ...:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you have written is not a list of a list of a list. As *wjandrea* has said:

> This is a list of lists of sets, not lists

Secondly, since I couldn't understand your question clearly, I suppose you need a method of extracting an specific value from each list.
For that, you can use **Numpy** and **Pandas** (assuming you are familiar with them, otherwise read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_quick_guide.htm) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_quick_guide.htm) for further information)

my way of doing so could be:

```
# in order to make a list of *temperatures* for *each* element we should first
# take the given array -- yours in this case -- and convert it into an array:
 
freq = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,22, 44, 54], [np.nan, 23, 43, 52]]).T

# then we would create a DataFrame out of our array using our elements' names as 
# the indexing name:

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(freq, index=["Cu", "Ag", "Au", "Pt"], columns=["temp_1", "temp_2", "temp_3"])
```

result:

```
    temp_1  temp_2  temp_3
Cu      1      1      0
Ag      2     22     23
Au      3     44     43
Pt      4     54     52
```

p.s.
You can also get, for example, "Ag" element's temperatures by writing:

```
data_frame.loc["Ag"]
```

Or if you wanted the whole temperature of one column, just write:

```
data_frame["temp_1"]
```

Comment: [[-1.8620689655172413, 298.0],
    ...:   [mpf('-395.13386225658188'),
    ...:    mpf('197.56693112829094'),
    ...:    mpf('395.13386225658188'),
    ...:    mpf('-395.13386225658188')]],
    ...:  [[-2.0, 298.0],
    ...:   [mpf('-5795.4864909536747'),
    ...:    mpf('2897.7432454768373'),
    ...:    mpf('5795.4864909536747'),
    ...:    mpf('-5795.4864909536747')]]]